# Can BeautifulSoup parse xml when certain tag is self-closing and not at the same time

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

Situation like the following.
**XML file:**

```
<tag1/>  
<tag2>some_data</tag2>
<tag1>some_another_data</tag1>
```

tag1 is sometimes self-closing and sometimes has data inside.

**code:**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
s = '<tag1/><tag2>some_data</tag2><tag1>some_another_data</tag1>'
soup1 = BeautifulStoneSoup(s)
soup2 = BeautifulStoneSoup(s, selfClosingTags=["tag1"])
print soup1.prettify()
print
print soup2.prettify()
```

**output:**

```
<tag1>
 <tag2>
  some_data
 </tag2>
</tag1>
<tag1>
 some_another_data
</tag1>

<tag1 />
<tag2>
 some_data
</tag2>
<tag1 />
some_another_data
```

In the first case tag1 eats the following tag (if it is not tag1 again), because there is no support of self-closing tags by default.
in the second case self-closing tag doesn't support child tags.

I just want to get structure as original xml document. Is it possible with BeautifulSoup? And if it is possible, then how to make all tags self-closing by default? There is a lot of xml files and I don't want to search all such situations manually.

Comment: I havn't used BeautifulSoup, but based on what you've said it looks like it isn't an XML parser at all, but an HTML parser.  (You don't specify which tags are self-closing for XML; it's *always* valid to write an element with no children either way.)  It looks like you're using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2):

I'd not recommend BeautifulSoup (not even for HTML parsing).  Use ElementTree from the standard library, or [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), if you need a more powerful XML library.

Comment: BeautifulSoup just seems more comfortable then ElementTree. And isn't lxml a wrapper to C library? I need to use it in GAE. Don't know if it will work. But anyway I'd like to make BeautifulSoup work if it is possible

Comment: BeautifulSoup specializes in parsing ill-formed HTML.  If you have good XML, use a pure XML parser.  There are options available on GAE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032724

Comment: @Ned: How is a question about Java XML parsing on GAE supposed to help concerning Python?

Comment: oops: I always forget that Java is available on GAE, and didn't notice that the question I linked to was about Java.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can tell BeautifulSoup 4 ("bs4") to use a different parser (such as lxml), by specifying it on the constructor. I would avoid earlier versions entirely, and avoid using the default parser with bs4 (for example, it fails to deal with omitted end-tags correctly).